# Canvas in Unity is slightly off to use on actual phone

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am currently working with Unity on a litle platformer for Android. However, I have noticed, that the canvas is just slightly off on my phone than it is in the preview from the unity editor. Here is the difference:

[image]

The upper picture is the unity editor, the lower one is from my Samsung S8. 
Now, it is clearly not about the black bars. I told the canvas to always render in a 16:9 ratio, so that is fine. However, if you notice the cross, it is just slightly closer to the bottom of the screen. Also to the left of the ground on my phone, you see a little blue line where the background peeks through. Again in the upper picture, this isnt the case. I know it is "just a few pixels" however I am wondering over what I am doing wrong.

I set the canvas to "Scale with screensize" So what could be the issue here?

Thanks for the help!

This is the Dpad: It is an image on the canvas. it works with buttons that are invisible but on top of the dpad. [image]

Comment: Is the control UI a screen space UI? Can you show the inspector values for the d-pad layout positioning?

Comment: It's likely that it's scaling with a different dpi on the phone

Comment: @Mikedg hi, I edited my question.

Comment: @NathanHeadley how could I interfere with that?

Comment: Not sure about in Unity, but native android allows you to find out what the scaling factor is, then you should factor that into how you position everything.

Comment: What happens if you tick "Preserve Aspect"?

Comment: @NathanHeadley this doesnt really change anything.. :(

Comment: Or it can be related to your anchor position, I don't know your anchor setup until you post screenshot. for example, you set the anchor of cross to screen's topleft, then it will keep the distance from your cross to topleft unchange. That is just an example, need to see your anchor for further advice

Comment: I got this problem too :/ have you got any solution @innomotionmedia?

Answer (score -2):

Samsung S8 native resolution is 2960x1440, so not 16:9? If we control the screen by width, 1440/9*16 = 2560, that would explain the black bar on the side? (2960-2560)/2 each side

Comment: As I said, the black bars are NOT the problem. It is the slightly off interface compared between the two images.

Comment: Or it can be related to your anchor position, I don't know your anchor setup until you post screenshot. for example, you set the anchor of cross to screen's topleft, then it will keep the distance from your cross to topleft unchange. That is just an example, need to see your anchor for further advice